# How to surround string with <p> tag that are not in <p> tag already - PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a `$text` string:

```
$text = "<body>
forth<br />
lalallalal<br />
lalal<br />
lalal2<br />
the first line
</body>";
```

And  a `$array_of_strings` :

```
$array_of_strings =  [
"the first line",
"lalallalal",
"lalal2",
"lalal",
"forth"
];
```

And I need to surround every string that in `$array_of_strings` into `<p>` tag

```
foreach ($array_of_strings as $string) {
    $text = str_replace($string, "<p>{$string}</p>", $text);
}
```

The output is `var_dump($text);`:

```
string(139) "<body>
<p>forth</p><br />
<p><p>lalal</p><p>lalal</p></p><br />
<p>lalal</p><br />
<p><p>lalal</p>2</p><br />
<p>the first line</p>
</body>"
```

As you can see there is a `<p>` tag in `<p>` tag. How can I escape it and have output like this:

```
string(132) "<body><p>
forth</p><br /><p>
lalallalal</p><br /><p>
lalal</p><br /><p>
lalal2</p><br /><p>
the first line
</p></body>"
```

Comment: How is your $string looks like?

Comment: Thats about inevitable when some of the search strings are sub-strings of other search strings.

Comment: What is happening here is `lalal` is a substring of `lalallalal` and hence the replacement occurs twice.. You have to handle that scenario

Comment: @Sujeet Sinha "You have to handle that scenario" That's why I ask it here, right now, I don't know how to handle it ^^

Comment: @MuthaFury It's in $array_of_strings

Comment: @Anant Sorry, I have fixed the $array_of_strings in my question.

Comment: @whitesiroi  check my answer please. it's the best solution for you and will match all the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way:

```
$replace = [];
foreach ($array_of_strings as $string) {
    $replace[$string] = "<p>$string</p>";
}

echo strtr($text, $replace);
```

Comment: Thank you very much mate for your help. I didn't know about strtr().

Answer (score 1):

Some of your $array_of_strings are substrings of the others. You need to look for line breaks as well in order to only get the entire string you are looking for. Also, you probably don't need the `<br />` tags once you've got the `<p></p>` sorted out.

Try changing your `str_replace` as follows:

```
foreach ($array_of_strings as $string) {
    $text = str_replace($string."<br />", "<p>{$string}</p>", $text);
}
```

Or if you need to keep those `<br />` tags in there:

```
foreach ($array_of_strings as $string) {
    $text = str_replace($string."<br />", "<p>{$string}</p><br />", $text);
}
```

Comment: plus1 Thank you for your help. $text is variable, sometimes there are no <br /> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try combining your Loop with some Regular Expression. The reason you are getting such an undesired result is obvious: `lalallalal` is exactly 2 Times `lalal`, so you should expect `<p>lalal</p><p>lalal</p>`. Logical huh? Anyways, you can bypass all those `str_replace`by building a Regular Expression with `Word Boundaries` like this:

```
<?php

$text = "<body>
            forth<br />
            lalallalal<br />
            lalal<br />
            lalal2<br />
            the first line
        </body>";

$array_of_strings =  array(
    "the first line",
    "lalallalal",
    "lalal2",
    "lalal",
    "forth"
);


// BUILD A REGEX ARRAY FROM THE $array_of_strings
$rxArray        = array();
foreach($array_of_strings as $string){
    $rxArray[]  = "#(\b" . preg_quote( trim($string) ) . "\b)#si";
}

$text  = preg_replace($rxArray, "<p>$1</p>", $text);

var_dump($rxArray);
var_dump($text);
```

Below is the result of the 2 `var_dump()` calls above in their respective order:

```
array (size=5)
      0 => string '#(\bthe first line\b)#si' (length=24)
      1 => string '#(\blalallalal\b)#si' (length=20)
      2 => string '#(\blalal2\b)#si' (length=16)
      3 => string '#(\blalal\b)#si' (length=15)
      4 => string '#(\bforth\b)#si' (length=15)

string '<body>
    <p>forth</p><br />
    <p>lalallalal</p><br />
    <p>lalal</p><br />
    <p>lalal2</p><br />
    <p>the first line</p>
    </body>' (length=141)
```

Confirm it for yourself [HERE](https://eval.in/596336).

Comment: plus1 Thank you very much for your help mate. It does work great.